# Getting error after installing docker toolbox on windows. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.0.75.2:2375

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

[image]

After installing docker toolbox, when tried to open kitematic, I am getting below error.

On clicking "Use VirtualBox", I get below error screen

[image]

Comment: What happens if you select "Use Virtualbox"?

Comment: You get a message that virtualbox is not installed. And I get the exact same message.

Comment: @ldg, I have edited my question with what happens if I click "Use VirtualBox"

Comment: Try Docker beta? :)

Comment: beta which was not working earlier started working. Thank you @ldg

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1843) which will be fixed soon, 
as a temporary solution please try to add this entry to your hosts file (%windir%\drivers\etc\hosts):

> 127.0.0.1 docker.local